# How to dynamically reference datasets in function call of linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
data("mtcars")
ncol(mtcars)

test <- function(string){
      fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl,
                     data = string)
      return(fit)
}
```

I'd like to be able to have the "string" variable evaluated as the dataset for a linear regression like so:

```
test("mtcars")
```

However, I get an error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) :    invalid 'envir' argument of
> type 'character'

I've tried using combinations of `eval` and `parse`, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get()` to search by name for an object.

```
test <- function(string){
  fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = get(string))
  return(fit)
}

test("mtcars")

# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = get(string))
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          cyl  
#      37.885       -2.876
```

---

You can add one more line to make the output look better. Notice the change of the `Call` part in the output. It turns from `data = get(string)` to `data = mtcars`.

```
test <- function(string){
  fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = get(string))
  fit$call$data <- as.name(string)
  return(fit)
}

test("mtcars")

# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          cyl  
#      37.885       -2.876
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this slight change to your code:

```
#Code
test <- function(string){
  fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl,
            data = eval(parse(text=string)))
  return(fit)
}
#Apply
test("mtcars")
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = eval(parse(text = string)))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl  
     37.885       -2.876
```

Comment: No, use `get` here. `eval(parse())` is not intended to be used for this (it should be avoided in general, valid use cases are rare). Debugging and maintaining code which uses `eval(parse())` is a nightmare. It's also slow.